# After uploading kernel to 5.0 in 18.04 hwe an error message appears

Tags: 18.04

after it uploads to kernel 5.0 (and for three days since that) it appears an error message. There could be any risk? I haven't notice something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could be a bit more specific about what the error message says and when it appears? Remember that we cannot see what you are seeing. Help us to help you.

Comment: To determine if there is any risk or identify the root cause of these errors, please inspect the logs by reading the contents of the file at: /var/log/syslog

Comment: The typical error message appears, answering if I want to send information to Ubuntu devs. I'll try to see the log next time it happens.